# PHP split / explode

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, explode

I currently have some text like this:

`W. 50DateWorkSuggested breakTotalMondayTuesday11/1217:00-01:0020:30-21:157:15Wednesday12/1217:00-01:0019:00-19:457:15ThursdayFridaySaturday15/1216:00-23:0020:00-20:456:15Sunday16/1217:00-01:0021:00-21:457:15Total:28W. 51DateWorkSuggested breakTotalMonday17/1217:00-01:0019:00-19:457:15TuesdayWednesday19/1217:00-00:0021:00-21:456:15Thursday20/1223:00-07:0003:00-03:457:15Friday21/1223:00-07:0002:30-03:157:15SaturdaySundayTotal:28W. 52DateWorkSuggested breakTotalMondayTuesdayWednesdayThursdayFridaySaturdaySundayTotal:0W. 1DateWorkSuggested breakTotalMonday------Total:0 Total number of hours: 77:45 Schedule for Month: December`

It originally looked different but I have removed the html tags as it was all in tables,

I now however want to spilt / explode this data so that theres one day on each line reading like:

```
Monday    10/12:
Tuesday   11/12: 17:00 - 01:00
Wednesday 12/12: 17:00 - 01:00
Thursday  13/12:
Friday    14/12:
Saturday: 15/12: 16:00 - 23:00
```

Thats an example for the first week, I have tried code like:

```
 preg_match_all (("/Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thusday|Fiday|Saturday|Sunday/"), $content, $parts ); 

    print_r ($parts);
```

But not really having any luck, so any help would be appreciated,

Thanks,

Jack.

ORIGINAL CODE WITH HTML TAGS:

```
<body> <table border=0 class=blackborder cellpadding=2 cellspacing=2> 
<tr><td><table class=blackborder width=315><tr><td><b>W. 50</b></td><td><B>Date</B></td><td><B>Work</B></td><td><B>Suggested break</B></td><td><B>Total</B></td><tr><td></tr><tr><td>Monday</tr><tr><td>Tuesday<td>11/12</td><td>17:00-01:00</td><td>20:30-21:15</td><td>7:15</td></tr><tr><td>Wednesday<td>12/12</td><td>17:00-01:00</td><td>19:00-19:45</td><td>7:15</td></tr><tr><td>Thursday</tr><tr><td>Friday</tr><tr><td>Saturday<td>15/12</td><td>16:00-23:00</td><td>20:00-20:45</td><td>6:15</td></tr><tr><td>Sunday<td>16/12</td><td>17:00-01:00</td><td>21:00-21:45</td><td>7:15</td></td></tr><tr><td>Total:</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>28</td></tr></table></td><td><table class=blackborder width=315><tr><td><b>W. 51</b></td><td><B>Date</B></td><td><B>Work</B></td><td><B>Suggested break</B></td><td><B>Total</B></td><tr><td></tr><tr><td>Monday<td>17/12</td><td>17:00-01:00</td><td>19:00-19:45</td><td>7:15</td></tr><tr><td>Tuesday</tr><tr><td>Wednesday<td>19/12</td><td>17:00-00:00</td><td>21:00-21:45</td><td>6:15</td></tr><tr><td>Thursday<td>20/12</td><td>23:00-07:00</td><td>03:00-03:45</td><td>7:15</td></tr><tr><td>Friday<td>21/12</td><td>23:00-07:00</td><td>02:30-03:15</td><td>7:15</td></tr><tr><td>Saturday</tr><tr><td>Sunday</td></tr><tr><td>Total:</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>28</td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td><table class=blackborder width=315><tr><td><b>W. 52</b></td><td><B>Date</B></td><td><B>Work</B></td><td><B>Suggested break</B></td><td><B>Total</B></td><tr><td></tr><tr><td>Monday</tr><tr><td>Tuesday</tr><tr><td>Wednesday</tr><tr><td>Thursday</tr><tr><td>Friday</tr><tr><td>Saturday</tr><tr><td>Sunday</td></tr><tr><td>Total:</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>0</td></tr></table></td><td><table class=blackborder width=315><tr><td><b>W. 1</b></td><td><B>Date</B></td><td><B>Work</B></td><td><B>Suggested break</B></td><td><B>Total</B></td><tr><td></tr><tr><td>Monday</td></tr><tr><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>-</td></tr><tr><td>Total:</td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>0</td></tr></table> </td> </tr> <tr> <td colspan=2> <b>Total number of hours:</b> 77:45<br> </td> </tr> </table> </body>
```

Comment: it would be easier if you kept it inside the table and just use PHP's DOMDocument http://us3.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php

Comment: Keep the HTML tags. It will be more easy to parse the HTML than this text.

Comment: i will show you code with HTML tags 1 min

Comment: @hakre what you edited in this question?

Comment: @Nileshpatel you can see edit log: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/13854689/revisions :)

Comment: original with html tags been added to above post now

Answer (score 1):

well i can get a day and time with regex

```
$str = 'W. 50DateWorkSuggested breakTotalMondayTuesday11/1217:00-01:0020:30-21:157:15Wednesday12/1217:00-01:0019:00-19:457:15ThursdayFridaySaturday15/1216:00-23:0020:00-20:456:15Sunday16/1217:00-01:0021:00-21:457:15Total:28W. 51DateWorkSuggested breakTotalMonday17/1217:00-01:0019:00-19:457:15TuesdayWednesday19/1217:00-00:0021:00-21:456:15Thursday20/1223:00-07:0003:00-03:457:15Friday21/1223:00-07:0002:30-03:157:15SaturdaySundayTotal:28W. 52DateWorkSuggested breakTotalMondayTuesdayWednesdayThursdayFridaySaturdaySundayTotal:0W. 1DateWorkSuggested breakTotalMonday------Total:0 Total number of hours: 77:45 Schedule for Month: December';
$ptr = "/(?P<day>:Monday|Tuesday|Wednesday|Thusday|Fiday|Saturday|Sunday?)(?P<time>([0-9:\/\- ]?)+)/";
preg_match_all($ptr, $str, $data);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($data);
echo '</pre>';
```

the output will be like this

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tuesday11/1217:00-01:0020:30-21:157:15
            [1] => Wednesday12/1217:00-01:0019:00-19:457:15
            [2] => Saturday15/1216:00-23:0020:00-20:456:15
            [3] => Sunday16/1217:00-01:0021:00-21:457:15
            [4] => Tuesday
            [5] => Wednesday19/1217:00-00:0021:00-21:456:15
            [6] => Saturday
            [7] => Sunday
            [8] => Tuesday
            [9] => Wednesday
            [10] => Saturday
            [11] => Sunday
        )

    [day] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tuesday
            [1] => Wednesday
            [2] => Saturday
            [3] => Sunday
            [4] => Tuesday
            [5] => Wednesday
            [6] => Saturday
            [7] => Sunday
            [8] => Tuesday
            [9] => Wednesday
            [10] => Saturday
            [11] => Sunday
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Tuesday
            [1] => Wednesday
            [2] => Saturday
            [3] => Sunday
            [4] => Tuesday
            [5] => Wednesday
            [6] => Saturday
            [7] => Sunday
            [8] => Tuesday
            [9] => Wednesday
            [10] => Saturday
            [11] => Sunday
        )

    [time] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11/1217:00-01:0020:30-21:157:15
            [1] => 12/1217:00-01:0019:00-19:457:15
            [2] => 15/1216:00-23:0020:00-20:456:15
            [3] => 16/1217:00-01:0021:00-21:457:15
            [4] => 
            [5] => 19/1217:00-00:0021:00-21:456:15
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 11/1217:00-01:0020:30-21:157:15
            [1] => 12/1217:00-01:0019:00-19:457:15
            [2] => 15/1216:00-23:0020:00-20:456:15
            [3] => 16/1217:00-01:0021:00-21:457:15
            [4] => 
            [5] => 19/1217:00-00:0021:00-21:456:15
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
            [1] => 
            [2] => 
            [3] => 
            [4] => 
            [5] => 
            [6] => 
            [7] => 
            [8] => 
            [9] => 
            [10] => 
            [11] => 
        )

)
```

then you can loop to make a data nice ;)

Comment: seems to work with my given code but im trying to implement it with $str = htmlspecialchars($html); and not showing any times or dates just names of week

Comment: (?P<week>([0-9]{1,2}\/[0-9]{1,2})) replcace with this to catch weeks

Comment: Sorry, I mean its only showing me days (except monday) and also have no times next to any of them... :S